# Double-Queue Code needs to be reduced

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can reduce this code to do the same thing but with 100 less characters?

It's a simple double edge queue that has pushHead,popHead,pushTail,popTail, as well as a way to access the length and isEmpty.

```
var makeDeque = function()
{
    var a= [];
    this.length= a.length=0;

    this.pushHead=function(v)
    {
        a.unshift(v);
    }
    this.popHead=function()
    {
        return a.shift();
    }

    this.pushTail=function(v)
    {
        a.push(v);
    }

    this.popTail=function()
    {
    return a.pop();
    }

    this.isEmpty=function()
    {
        return a.length===0;
    }

    return this;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544265/pointers-and-array-class-in-javascript/18544420#18544420

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the manual array handling. I guess you can't get any shorter than this (you could shorten variable names, but the code probably needs to be at least this long).

```
function Deque() {}
Deque.prototype = new Array();
var prot = Deque.prototype;
prot.pushHead = Deque.prototype.unshift;
prot.popHead = Deque.prototype.shift;
prot.pushTail = Deque.prototype.push
prot.popTail = Deque.prototype.pop
prot.isEmpty = function() {return this.length == 0}
```

This way, you also get all the functionality of the default `Arrays` as well. `Deque` in this example effectively a sub-class of the `Array` class.