# Pointers and array class in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way for me to shorten this code by using pointers?
I need to make a class that has mostly the same function as a given array class unshift,shift,push and pop but with different names.

```
var makeDeque = function()
{
    var a= [], r=new Array(a);

    length = r.length=0;

    pushHead=function(v)
    {
        r.unshift(v);
    }

    popHead=function()
    {
        return r.shift();
    }

    pushTail=function(v)
    {
        r.push(v);
    }

    popTail=function()
    {
        return r.pop();
    }

    isEmpty=function()
    {
        return r.length===0;
    }

    return this;
};    

(function() {
   var dq = makeDeque();

   dq.pushTail(4);
   dq.pushHead(3);
   dq.pushHead(2);
   dq.pushHead("one");
   dq.pushTail("five");
   print("length " + dq.length + "last item: " + dq.popTail());
   while (!dq.isEmpty())
      print(dq.popHead());
})();
```

Output should be

length 5last item: five
one
2
3
4

Thanks!

Comment: `var a= [], r=new Array(a);` What is the point of `r`? Why not just use `a`?

Comment: Have a look at my answer, if I remember correctly you needed 174 chars and I made it.

Comment: What is a pointer in JS?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but why not just add the extra methods you need to the Array prototype and call it directly?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to make a class that has mostly the same function as a given array class unshift,shift,push and pop but with different names.

I suppose you could add these "new" methods to `Array.prototype`.

Comment: How would I go upon doing that?

Comment: @user2723588 `Array.prototype.myFunction = function() {};`,`Array.prototype.someProperty = 'hi';` etc, then whenever you make a new array that function/property will be available for use.

Comment: So would it be Array.makeDequeue= function()
{
 pushHead=this.unshift(v);
};

Comment: I tried and the smallest I could get was 174 chars compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Like this perhaps?

```
var makeDeque = (function (ap) {
    var Deque = {
        length: 0,
        pushHead: ap.unshift,
        popHead: ap.shift,
        pushTail: ap.push,
        popTail: ap.pop,
        isEmpty: function () {
            return !this.length;
        }
    };

    return function () { 
        return Object.create(Deque); 
    };
})(Array.prototype);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ac3x/)

If it's still too long, you can always directly augment `Array.prototype` like others already mentionned. We agree that it's all experimental here and the only goal is to save characters.

```
!function (ap) {
    ap.pushHead = ap.unshift;
    ap.popHead = ap.shift;
    ap.pushTail = ap.push;
    ap.popTail = ap.pop;
    ap.isEmpty = function () {
        return !this.length;
    };
}(Array.prototype);

function makeDeque() {
    return [];
}
```

**This can be compressed to 174 chars:**

```
function makeDeque(){return[]}!function(e){e.pushHead=e.unshift;e.popHead=e.shift;e.pushTail=e.push;e.popTail=e.pop;e.isEmpty=function(){return!this.length}}(Array.prototype)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ac3x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need this, but my suggestions per best practice are:

1. Don't override the `Array.prototype`. The reason for this is because other libraries might try to do the same, and if you include these libraries into yours, there will be conflicts.
2. This code is not needed. `var a= [], r=new Array(a);`. You only need ...`a = [];`.
3. Ensure you are creating a real class. In your code, `makeDeque` is not doing what you want. It is returning `this` which when a function is not called with the `new` keyword will be the same as the `window` object (or `undefined` if you are using what is called as "strict mode"). In other words, you have made a lot of globals (which are usually a no-no, as they can conflict with other code too).
4. When you build a class, it is good to add to the `prototype` of your *custom* class. This is because the methods will only be built into memory one time and will be shared by all such objects.

So I would first refactor into something like this:

```
var makeDeque = (function() { // We don't need this wrapper in this case, as we don't have static properties, but I've kept it here since we do want to encapsulate variables in my example below this one (and sometimes you do need static properties).

    function makeDeque () {
        if (!(this instanceof makeDeque)) { // This block allows you to call makeDeque without using the "new" keyword (we will do it for the person using makeDeque)
            return new makeDeque();
        }
        this.r = [];
        this.length = 0;
    }

    makeDeque.prototype.setLength = function () {
        return this.length = this.r.length;
    };

    makeDeque.prototype.pushHead=function(v) {
        this.r.unshift(v);
        this.setLength();
    };

    makeDeque.prototype.popHead=function() {
        return this.r.shift();
        this.setLength();
    };

    makeDeque.prototype.pushTail=function(v){
        this.r.push(v);
        this.setLength();
    };

    makeDeque.prototype.popTail=function() {
        return this.r.pop();
        this.setLength();
    };

    makeDeque.prototype.isEmpty=function() {
        return this.r.length === 0;
    };

    return makeDeque;
}());
```

Now you could shorten this as follows, but I wouldn't recommend doing this, since, as it was well said by Donald Knuth, "premature optimization is the root of all evil". If you try to shorten your code, it may make it inflexible.

```
var makeDeque = (function() {

    function makeDeque () {
        if (!(this instanceof makeDeque)) {
            return new makeDeque();
        }
        this.r = [];
        this.length = 0;
    }

    makeDeque.prototype.setLength = function () {
        return this.length = this.r.length;
    };


    for (var i=0, methodArray = [
        ['pushHead', 'unshift'], ['popHead', 'shift'], ['pushTail', 'push'], ['popTail', 'pop']
    ]; i < methodArray.length; i++) {

        makeDeque.prototype[methodArray[i][0]] = (function (i) { // We need to make a function and immediately pass in 'i' here because otherwise, the 'i' inside this function will end up being set to the value of 'i' after it ends this loop as opposed to the 'i' which varies with each loop. This is a common "gotcha" of JavaScript
            return function () {
                var ret = this.r[methodArray[i][1]].apply(this.r, arguments);
                this.setLength();
                return ret;
            };
        }(i));
    } 

    makeDeque.prototype.isEmpty=function() {
        return this.r.length === 0;
    };

    return makeDeque;
}());
```

If you need to get the length by a `length` property, as opposed to a method like setLength() which sets it manually after each update, either of the above code samples could be shortened by avoiding the setLength() method, but you'd need to use the `Object.defineProperty` which does not work (or does not work fully) in older browsers like IE < 9.

Comment: I think his goal was smallest as possible, probably for some kind of challenge? If I remember correctly he had some sort of 174 chars special rule. That's quite funny because the smallest implementation I could find by directly augmenting `Array.prototype` has 174 chars exactly.

Comment: Remember correctly how? The user doesn't have a name and didn't mention this. Is it that the name "makeDeque" is similar?

Comment: Sorry, should have checked user profile--i see from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525013/efficient-deque-function